# Как реализовать ассоциативный массив на Java?

Tags: php, java

Пытаюсь реализовать [этот php код](https://github.com/rembish/TextAtAnyCost/blob/master/rtf.php) на `java`. Как кто-то написал в комментариях это

```
 $table = array(
    0x83 => 0x00c9, 0x84 => 0x00d1, 0x87 => 0x00e1, 0x8e => 0x00e9, 0x92 => 0x00ed, 
    0x96 => 0x00f1, 0x97 => 0x00f3, 0x9c => 0x00fa, 0xe7 => 0x00c1, 0xea => 0x00cd, 
    0xee => 0x00d3, 0xf2 => 0x00da
);
```

ассоциативный массив. В Java таких нет. Как его реализовать?

Comment: Судя по коду в гитхаб он передаёт символ в rtf и функция переделывает его в html unicode в hexadecimal формат и возвращает его, говоря проще она 0х меняет на &#х, на выходе для первого элемента ассоциативного массива будет &#х00с9

Comment: @fadey да, так и есть)) Но мне бы реализовать такой же класс на Java. А ассоциативных массивов в java нет.

Comment: Как же нет, hashmap можешь использовать, в java есть куда больше чем в php) если не справишься чуть позже сделаю код на java

Comment: @fadey ага. Спасибо за подсказку. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация массива на `java`.

```
   HashMap <Integer, Integer> associativeArray = new HashMap<>(13);
    associativeArray.put(0x83, 0x00c9);
    associativeArray.put(0x00d1, 0x87);
    associativeArray.put(0x87, 0x00e1);
    associativeArray.put(0x8e, 0x00e9);
    associativeArray.put(0x92, 0x00ed);
    associativeArray.put(0x96, 0x00f1);
    associativeArray.put(0x97, 0x00f3);
    associativeArray.put(0x9c, 0x00fa);
    associativeArray.put(0xe7, 0x00c1);
    associativeArray.put(0xea,0x00cd);
    associativeArray.put(0xee, 0x00d3);
    associativeArray.put(0xf2, 0x00da);
```

Comment: Словарём он называется, а не массивом.

Answer (score 0):

Держи код твоей функции сделал на коленке, не проверял но должно все работать, как заполнить массив тебе уже показали.

```
public String getcodes(String code){
    HashMap<String, String> hexCodes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String val=hexCodes.get(code);
    return val.replace("0x","&#x")
}
```

Comment: Можно заменить `HashMap<String, String> hexCodes = new HashMap<String, String>();` -> `HashMap<String, String> hexCodes = new HashMap();`. Кроме то, словарь у вас пустой. И если ключа `code` не будет то `hexCodes.get(` вернет `null` и `val.replace` упадет с `NullPointerException` :)

Comment: Да естественно надо заполнить, обработку исключений уже по логике делать. Все верно подмечено, писалось на коленке. Так же если работать с integer будет другой код.